# Git Pull on Live Server from Local Dev Server

Tags: git

I've had a look around on google for hours about this problem and I still can't seem to find anything.

We have just set up a local dev server at work, which we want to store the git repositories on. I could sit here and explain for days why and how,. but ultimately this is what i want the workflow to be:

- Dev works on their copy
- Commits to dev (or staging server)
- Live server 'pulls' from staging server.

In my mind, the staging server will need to be online and such for it to work - is this correct? Or is there a way we can pull from the live server via a reverse SSH or something (i've just made that up).

Sorry - i'm a noob to Git and server stuff, so please be gentle :)

Comment: Is the staging server a live installation of your application or is it just a remote repository for your codebase?

Comment: The staging server is a live installation - so managers and other devs  can preview the site before it is put live

Comment: Is it a requirement that the staging installation also dooe double duty as a remote repository, or can the main remote for the project exist on a different system?

Comment: We want to avoid it being on the live server - and while we have this internal server at our disposal, it seems to logical solution

Answer (score 0):

There are probably people better than me at server config. But what I know, you can play on your own machine first:

- Create a repo in a folder called "liveserver" for example
- Clone it as bare repo in a folder called "devserver". This one is not made to be modified directly.
- Now clone it as non-bare in folders called "user1", "user2" and commit, pull, push data from them and see what happens on your devserver and liveserver.

As for the SSH config of the servers, I know I used github documentation when I had a problem once (since that's their job, they explain it well) but honestly I never really worked on that part

Answer (score 0):

Here several random thoughts on this:

- You can use the same repository for live and development. And one branch will be `live` and another will be `development`. You can easy merge between these two branches within one repository. No pushing / pulling will be required.
- You can setup two repositories one for `live`, another for `development` in two folders on one server. And push / pull between them without using SSH, just locally.
- If you're plan to use two servers with SSH, probably you will find following article [interesting](http://tumblr.intranation.com/post/766290565/how-set-up-your-own-private-git-server-linux).

But frankly if there are no special requirements on security of the workflow (i.e. separating live and development into two physical locations) I believe first approach will be just fine to stultify your needs — this is the way how branches intended to be used.